# same jsp page for add and edit

Tags: jsp, addition, edit

i am new in struts 1.3 application development , i requirement is that what ever the forms i am developing i have to make 2 forms of same kind one for add purpose and another for edit purpose means i have a web form in that i have two fields one for entering the code and another for entering the name and a save button to save the data into database and when the user is in the add mode i display this from and in edit mode i display the other form which has got a hidden field ,one field for displaying the code and another is for displaying the name and the update button . through this he can update the data now my requirement is that can i use same form for adding and editing the information i have googled i found the that this can be done by using struts layout but not much information is available . if anybody can give me the some hint how to achieve this would be helpful for me

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Try to put some punctuation in your sentences, and to start sentences with an upper-case letter. Also, it's "I", not "i".

Answer (score 0):

As @JB Nizet  mentioned please format your post for clarity. Also from what I can understand, you want to use same jsp for add/edit. I would suggest having a hidden parameter in your JSP to indicate the action type i'e Add/Edit. Then depending on the action type you can show/hide form elements.

Please read a reference book on Struts for more details.